# How to add an attribute to request like the 'user' variable

Tags: django

I want to create a new variable which is always available like how the 'user' variable works.

Here is my myapp/context_processors.py

```
def patient_selected(request):

print(hasattr(request, 'patient_selected_id'))
print( 'patient_selected_id' in locals())
print( 'patient_selected_id' in globals())

if not hasattr(request, 'patient_selected_id'):
    request.patient_selected_id = 0

return {"patient_selected_id": 0}
```

The problem is, it always prints 'false'. It seems like I cannot add an attribute to the request, nor create a variable constantly available. 
BTW, I have added this context_processors.py to settings.
Here is my setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'hrs.context_processors.patient_selected',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

EDIT:
After reading source codes, it seems like the `user` variable is not actually created once and live forever. The Middleware and context_processor add a variable `user` for every request, and this 'user' is actually pulled from session.

My original design is: Once a patient is selected, all following pages will be about this patient. Thus, I would like to make this patient's id always available. Instead of pass this id all around, I want to save it(somewhere) once and always available until another patient is selected.

However now, considering the complexity of `user` variable, I may give up the fancy way. Simply put this id as a parameter in every request url should be easier.

Comment: You do this with *middleware*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django does that with [*middleware* <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/middleware/#middleware). In fact setting the `.user` attribute is done with middleware as well. Indeed, you can see this in the [**`AuthenticationMiddleware`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py#L16):

> ```
> class AuthenticationMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
>     def process_request(self, request):
>         assert hasattr(request, 'session'), (
>             "The Django authentication middleware requires session middleware "
>             "to be installed. Edit your MIDDLEWARE%s setting to insert "
>             "'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' before "
>             "'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'."
>         ) % ("_CLASSES" if settings.MIDDLEWARE is None else "")
>         request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
> ```

If you remove the `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'` string from the [**`MIDDLEWARE`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE), then the `request.user` will no longer be set.

You can thus implement your own middleware. For example with:

```
# app/middleware.py

from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class PatientSelectIdMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not hasattr(request, 'patient_selected_id'):
            request.patient_selected_id = 0
```

Next you need to add the `'app.PatientSelectIdMiddleware'` middleware to the `MIDDLEWARE` setting.

Comment: I printed `print(hasattr(request, 'patient_selected_id'))` right before the `def ...` line. Then I just clicked "home" and "about" page[empty pages other than a string]. Yet, it still print `False`. Should there be some special way to add an attribute to request?

Comment: I think I may get it. I printed `print(hasattr(request, user))` in the 'AuthenticationMiddleware', and it also keep printing 'False'. In fact, the 'user' variable is pulled from `request.session` and inserted for every quest. It looks like a constant variable but not that simple. The middleware cannot solve my need.

Comment: Nowadays, should be `app.middleware.PatientSelectIdMiddleware` that's added to `MIDDLEWARE`.